# Wildcard Search for a numeric range

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, where-clause, sql-like

I am trying to filter out a column (plan_name) which have internet plans of customers. Eg (200GB Fast Unlimited,Free Additional Mailbox,Unlimited VDSL...). I specifically want to **filter out plans which do not have any numbers in them**. The column is of type varchar2 and I'm querying an Oracle database. I have written the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM   plans
WHERE  plan_name NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

However, this code still returns plans like 200GB fast that have numbers in them? Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Syntax is here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html

Answer (score 4):

Oracle's `like` syntax does not support the kind of pattern matching you are trying. This is SQL Server syntax. Oracle interprets the pattern as a *litteral* `'[0-9]'` (which, obviously, something like `'200GB'`does not match).

However, unlike SQL Server, Oracle has proper suport for regular expression, through the `regexp_*` functions. If you want values that contain no digit, you can do:

```
where not regexp_like(plan_name, '\d')
```

Comment: Thank you very much GMB! :)